# Unknown Display trying to connect external Monitor to Laptop via Mini-DisplayPort

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, displayport

I got a new laptop with an Nvidia GTX 970 + integrated Intel Graphics and got an Acer XB280HK Monitor with Gsync for optimal viewing pleasure. On Win10 everything works fine (dual boot). However if I try to connect the monitor when using ubuntu (mini-displayport) it will only display 1024x768 resolution.

After reading a lot on this site and elsewhere I tried a few different things, especially installing different drivers for the nvidia-card (tried proprietary as well as nouveau) installing bumblebee etc. etc. edited my xorg.conf here and there,trying to change things with the Nvidia X Server Settings,...

To no avail.

I really hope you guys have some more ideas what I can try....here's my current xrandr -q output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2932 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0  
1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
1600x1024      60.2  
1400x1050      60.0  
1280x1024      60.0  
1440x900       59.9  
1280x960       60.0  
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1152x864       60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected 1024x768+1908+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       60.0* 
800x600        60.3     56.2  
848x480        60.0  
640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Edit: Thanks for making it look nicer, Sir!
Can nobody help, though? I also tried to manually set another resolution for the monitor using xrandr using the following commands both for 60hz, 30hz and 1920x1080 resolution:

```
cvt 3840 2160 30
xrandr --newmode 3840x2160_30.00 338.75  3840 4080 4488 5136  2160 2163 2168 2200 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP2 "3840x2160_30.00"
```

However the as soon as i change the resolution to that the monitor will say "no signal" and after a while the display will be automatically turned off in the display settings.

Any ideas? Else I guess will have to return the monitor if possible...

Edit2: Oh, I forgot: I'm using Ubuntu 15.04!

Comment: Can people see this when it's a few ours old or what are my chances to still get an answer?